# Strategy for dealing with a pandas multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

A library hands me a pandas dataframe with a MultiIndex.
The results look like:

```
xf.index
DatetimeIndex(['2011-03-31', '2011-04-01', '2011-04-04', '2011-04-05',
               '2011-04-06', '2011-04-07', '2011-04-08', '2011-04-11',
               '2011-04-12', '2011-04-13',
               ...
               '2017-10-19', '2017-10-20', '2017-10-23', '2017-10-24',
               '2017-10-25', '2017-10-26', '2017-10-27', '2017-10-30',
               '2017-10-31', '2017-11-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'date', length=1702, freq=None)

xf.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'jan', u'feb', u'mar'], [u'PRICE', u'AMOUNT', u'NAME', u'STYLE']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

The basic idea is that for the months jan, feb, mar there are some information fields (price, amount, name, style) that are assessed each day.

I'm really inept manipulating this multiindex.

The sort of things i need to do:

- Modify existing 2nd level columns.  Eg.  make all 'names' lowercase.
- Add new columns, for example, "modified_name".  This would be
  applicable to all of jan, feb, and march.

I don't know if I should just try to flatten the whole column index into a single level (so that there is one column, 'month' that has a value of either 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', and then the other existing level 2 columns (price, amount, name, style).  I don't need the multiindex.

How would I collapse the dataframe into that?

Or are there ways to modify and add columns under the hierarchical index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest is create classic columns by reshape - get `MultiIndex` as index by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.stack(0)
```

And then modify columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
df['new_col'] = 1
```

and last reshape back by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

Sample:

```
i = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2011-03-31', '2011-04-01', '2011-04-04', '2011-04-05',
               '2011-04-06', '2011-04-07', '2011-04-08', '2011-04-11',
               '2011-04-12', '2011-04-13'])
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[u'jan', u'feb'],[u'PRICE', u'AMOUNT', u'NAME']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(len(i), 6)),index=i, columns=cols)

print (df)
             jan               feb            
           PRICE AMOUNT NAME PRICE AMOUNT NAME
2011-03-31     2      7    3     6      0    5
2011-04-01     6      2    5     0      4    2
2011-04-04     9      0    7     2      7    9
2011-04-05     5      3    5     7      9    9
2011-04-06     1      4    4     1      6    3
2011-04-07     1      7    4     9      6    7
2011-04-08     6      1    7     4      4    2
2011-04-11     7      5    6     8      0    3
2011-04-12     3      3    9     2      4    0
2011-04-13     0      0    1     9      0    3
```

---

```
df = df.stack(0)
print (df)
                AMOUNT  NAME  PRICE
2011-03-31 feb       0     5      6
           jan       7     3      2
2011-04-01 feb       4     2      0
           jan       2     5      6
2011-04-04 feb       7     9      2
           jan       0     7      9
2011-04-05 feb       9     9      7
           jan       3     5      5
2011-04-06 feb       6     3      1
           jan       4     4      1
2011-04-07 feb       6     7      9
           jan       7     4      1
2011-04-08 feb       4     2      4
           jan       1     7      6
2011-04-11 feb       0     3      8
           jan       5     6      7
2011-04-12 feb       4     0      2
           jan       3     9      3
2011-04-13 feb       0     3      9
           jan       0     1      0
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
df['new'] = 1

df = df.unstack().swaplevel(0,1,1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
              feb                   jan               
           amount name new price amount name new price
2011-03-31      0    5   1     6      7    3   1     2
2011-04-01      4    2   1     0      2    5   1     6
2011-04-04      7    9   1     2      0    7   1     9
2011-04-05      9    9   1     7      3    5   1     5
2011-04-06      6    3   1     1      4    4   1     1
2011-04-07      6    7   1     9      7    4   1     1
2011-04-08      4    2   1     4      1    7   1     6
2011-04-11      0    3   1     8      5    6   1     7
2011-04-12      4    0   1     2      3    9   1     3
2011-04-13      0    3   1     9      0    1   1     0
```

Another solution is create new `MultiIndex` and for new column [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) new `DataFrame` to original:

```
a = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
b = df.columns.get_level_values(1).str.lower()
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a,b])

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a.unique(),['new']])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=mux, index=df.index)
print (df1)
           jan feb
           new new
2011-03-31   1   1
2011-04-01   1   1
2011-04-04   1   1
2011-04-05   1   1
2011-04-06   1   1
2011-04-07   1   1
2011-04-08   1   1
2011-04-11   1   1
2011-04-12   1   1
2011-04-13   1   1

df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
              feb                   jan               
           amount name new price amount name new price
2011-03-31      0    5   1     6      7    3   1     2
2011-04-01      4    2   1     0      2    5   1     6
2011-04-04      7    9   1     2      0    7   1     9
2011-04-05      9    9   1     7      3    5   1     5
2011-04-06      6    3   1     1      4    4   1     1
2011-04-07      6    7   1     9      7    4   1     1
2011-04-08      4    2   1     4      1    7   1     6
2011-04-11      0    3   1     8      5    6   1     7
2011-04-12      4    0   1     2      3    9   1     3
2011-04-13      0    3   1     9      0    1   1     0
```